# Adding #document nodes as children

Tags: node.js, parent-child, xmldom

I am using `node` and `xmldom`. On ocasion I parse XML from a string with the intention of adding it as a child to another element. However, I am confused by the following code:

```
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var s   = require('xmldom').DOMSerializer;

var childToBe = new dom().parseFromString('<div id="foo">Text</div>');
var parent = nodeWhereIWantToInsertChild();

parent.appendChild(childToBe);
```

This works just fine, and when I serialize it, I get what I expected

```
<parent><div id="foo">Text</div></parent>
```

Therefore, since `div` is the child of `parent`,

```
parent.childNodes[0].nodeName == 'div' // is true as expected.
```

Then why is

```
childToBe.nodeName == '#document' // ->True ????
childToBe.getAttribute('id') // ->Error, no method 'getAttribute'
```

If `childToBe` is a #document and I appended it to `parent`, why doesn't parent have a #document child?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFromString` returns a `Document` instance, not an `Element` instance. Your `appendChild` call should probably be throwing an exception since `Document` is not allowed as a child of `Element`, but the Node parser implementation probably doesn't bother checking.

What you probably want is to get the root element of the document:

```
var doc = new dom().parseFromString('<div id="foo">Text</div>');
var childToBe = doc.documentElement;
```